# Совмещение 2-х асинхронных библиотек Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, асинхронность, asyncio

пытаюсь написать скрипт, в котором должны работать 2 асинхронные библиотеки: `websockets` и `aiogram`. `websockets` создает соединение для `wws api`, a `aiogram` по совместительству должен быть еще и `producer` для него, буду благодарен за совет или указание ошибок.

```
import asyncio
import websockets

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types


API_TOKEN = ''

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

#Обычный handler для приема любых сообщений
@dp.message_handler()
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)



#Здесь начинается websocket
#Цикл для ожидания сообщения для отправки в API
async def producer_handler(websocket):
    while True:
        message = #producer() сдесь должен быть прерывание от телеграм
        await websocket.send(message)


#Цикл для чтения сообщений от API
async def consumer_handler(websocket):
    async for message_wws in websocket:
        print(message_wws)


#Сама петля с 2мя задачами, если нет прерывания от ввода, выполняется чтение

async def consume():
    websocket_resource_url = f"wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv"
    async with websockets.connect(websocket_resource_url) as websocket:
        consumer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(consumer_handler(websocket))
        producer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(producer_handler(websocket))
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait([consumer_task, producer_task],return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        for task in pending:
            task.cancel()




#Здесь я пытаюсь запустить 2 незавершающихся петли паралельно(пробывал все из официальной документации, ставил их как задачи и все равно не понял)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(consume(), executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Ошибка в основном:

```
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Executor._startup_polling' was never awaited
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Executor._shutdown_polling' was never awaited
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая же проблема, попробуйте:

```
# --- Ваш код ---

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dp.loop.create_task(consume())
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Только позже у меня возникла после этого уже другая ошибка: asyncio.exceptions.timeouterror

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, к сожалению при использовании вашего варианта петля dp.loop.create_task(consume()) будет запущена первой, а так как она не имеет конца, будет блокирующей, поэтому executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True) никогда не запуститься. В принципе поэтому я и пытался использовать asyncio.gather , что бы запустить их параллельно.